# Fail to close connection when using SseEmitter in Flux.subscribe

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, server-sent-events

I'm working on a SpringBoot web api related to large language model, which calls the api of upstream server and return the results to the front-end after processing. Content type of upstream server api is `text/event-stream`, so `WebClient` is used to process sse message from upstream server. And my response to client is also in the form of sse, so `SseEmitter` is used. Code of method:

```
@GetMapping("")
    public SseEmitter chat(@Validated ChatRequest request) { 
        // ...
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://example.com");
        SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter();
        ModelChatRequest modelChatRequest = modelChatRequest();

        Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> eventStream = webClient.post()
                .uri("/v1/chat/completions")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(modelChatRequest))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(new ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>>() {
                })
                .doOnComplete(()->{
                    sseEmitter.complete();
                })
                .doOnError((Throwable t)->{
                    log.error("...", t);
                });
        Disposable subscription = eventStream.subscribe(event -> {
            try {
                String data = event.data();
                if (!data.equals("[DONE]")) {
                    // part of text generated by model
                    String content = (new ObjectMapper().readValue(data, new TypeReference<ModelChatVO>() {})).getChoices().get(0).getDelta().getContent();
                    if (!StringUtils.isBlank(content)) {
                        builder.append(content);
                    }
                    sseEmitter.send(content);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                sseEmitter.completeWithError(e);
            }
        });

        return sseEmitter;
    }
```

I tested the api using postman. And it turned out that the connection won't close even if `sseEmitter.complete()` is called. I found that because no `Connection closed` is shown in postman. And connection time shown in postman increases until timeout. The image below shows a sse api that functions well:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxcSd.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GFOB.png)

Server side timeout message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kurN.png)

To figure out why it's not right, I tried some other situations, and all of them behave properly.

Firstly, I created the sseEmitter, and in a new thread call `sseEmitter.send()` for 10 times in for loop and then call `sseEmitter.complete()`. In this situation, no webClient of Flux is used.

Secondly, `WebClient` is used to call upstream api, and `SseEmitter.complete()` is called in `doOnComplete()`, but no data is sent using sseEmitter. That is to say, no `sseEmitter` is used in the consumer of subscriber of Flux.

Thirdly, I mocked a Flux, and send data in the consumer of the subscribe of the Flux.

Since all of them works well, maybe the problem happens when sseEmitter is used in a subscriber of Flux generated from WebClient response...

I haven't been learning Java for long, so maybe the question might be terrible. And my english is not good as well. So thank you very much for finish reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the SseEmiter is closed properly you should write a `.doFinally()` clause where you write `sseEmiter.complete()`.
So like a try catch finally you can't miss a moment when it isn't closed.

I do exactly like you to use OpenAI endpoint and it works fine. In your subscribe you should avoid doing a huge try catch like that because you might have an error and complete the sseEmitter for a wrong reason. You should only wrap the sseEmitter.send in a try / catch, but throw a RuntimeException, the doFinally will be called.